# Countable base of a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am sure some flavor of this question has been asked; I just have not been able to find it.  I am not looking for a proof, but rather verification of or a counter-example dispelling a property of finite metric spaces.

Rudin's definition of a base of a metric space in problem 23 of chapter 2 of *Principle of Mathematical Analysis* is a collection $\{V_\alpha\}$ of open subsets of a metric space $X$, such that "For every $x\in X$ and every $G\subset X$ [where] $x\in G$, we have $x\in V_\alpha\subset G$ for some $\alpha$."

His definition of countable is a one-to-one correspondence between a set and $\mathbb{N}$, therefore infinite, and not just a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, which is finite.

In problem 25, it is to be proved that every compact metric space has a **countable** base.  To me, this implies, by his definitions, that all compact metric spaces are infinite.

My understanding is that a finite metric space would be compact.  My thought is that this follows from the fact that a finite subset of a compact metric space is compact and can itself be considered a metric space. Is my understanding that every finite metric space is compact incorrect or would it not be considered such?  Can metric spaces actually be thought of in this manner removed from any space, in which it is embedded?

I can show that a finite metric space has a finite base.  Is this just a slightly unclear question with respect to Rudin's definitions?

Comment: I guess Rudin should have written "an at most countable base", because yes, after all, finite metric spaces are compact and a base is a subset of the power set, so it can't possibly be infinite.

Comment: @Cauchy Excellent. That is what I thought, but I was not sure I was missing something. Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: For many Mathematicians countable includes finite! I don't think Rudin has made any error.

Comment: I have not read this book but I suggest you double-check his def'n of countable. I prefer countable to mean not-uncountable, i.e. finite or countably infinite.

Comment: I agree.  I have seen countable defined to cover finite and countable infinity too.  It seems Rudin switched gears from his previous definition or really wanted to address the case of infinite metric spaces.  I just wanted to make sure there was not something I was not aware of with the definition a finite metric space (not that I could determine there should be).   I appreciate all of the responses.  Thank you.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  Yes, he explicitly defines at most countable to accommodate both finite and countably infinite.